# PHP MySQL Unknown column 'address' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, list, field

There are quite a few posts on this similar question, but still I cannot get a clear answer for my code, which is for PHP and MySQL combination. I always got the error message after submitted the forms. Definitely it is related to the syntax. Interestingly mysql did not complain, nor does my apache, but on my browser (firefox).

```
$add_master_sql = "INSERT INTO master_name (date_added, date_modified, f_name, l_name)
VALUES (now(), now(), '".$_POST["f_name"]."', '".$_POST["l_name"]."')";
$add_master_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_master_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

and my MYSQL code is:

```
CREATE TABLE master_name (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  date_added DATETIME,
  date_modified DATETIME,
  f_name VARCHAR (75),
  l_name VARCHAR (75)
);
```

Something may be related to the quotation, but I double checked the match, which is fine. Can anybody help me out of this?

Comment: Hello SQL injection.

Comment: Could you post the error message you got? It will definitely help.

Comment: The error/warning message is: Unknown column 'address' in 'field list'

Comment: I first posted the problem on another forum: http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/183777-php-parsing-quotation.html  But nobody was interested in.

Comment: Are you sure this is the line where error is thrown?

Comment: Yes, sometime my apache log indicated: [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
 in /var/www/PHP+MySQL+Apache/20/addentry.php on line 71, referer: http://localhost/PHP+MySQL+Apache/20/addentry.php   But that was not always. I am aware the error message is different from my post, but the problem is always the same. I am learning PHP-MySQL by myself. The code is copied from the book "SAMS teach yourself PHP, MySQL and Apache all in one", page 390 ~ 414 for chapter 20. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ivan: according to Amazon, the latest released edition of that book was published in **2008**. I strongly recommend reusing it as a doorstop and finding a more recent and less incorrect publication to learn from. Any book that recommends directly feeding user input into SQL is not worth pirating, let alone actually paying for.

Comment: @Ivan this is completely different error. Can you make your mind and stop for just one?

Comment: It is most unlikely this line is causing the error `Unknown column 'address'` as you don't reference any such column. A good technique is to `echo $add_master_sql;` before you execute it, and then run it against your db directly e.g. in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: If you're not sure which error you're getting, stop your web server, delete the log file, and restart it. Then, you know any new errors are directly related to your current testing.

Comment: As @Karpie said, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You **really** should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 3):

More important is to use pdo prepared queries to avoid possible sql injection.

```
<?php
// configuration
$dbtype     = "sqlite";
$dbhost             = "localhost";
$dbname     = "test";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "admin";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// new data
$dateAdded = getdate();
$dateModified = getdate();
$f_name = $_POST["f_name"];
$l_name = $_POST["l_name"];

// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO master_name (date_added, date_modified, f_name, l_name) VALUES (:f_name, :l_name, :dateAdded, :dateModified)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':dateAdded'=>$dateAdded ,
                  ':dateModified'=>$dateModified,
                  ':f_name'=>$f_name,
                  ':l_name'=>$l_name));    

?>
```

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to use PDO. However, you have 4 columns, 2 values... Also, in my experience PDO cannot reuse the same bound variable in multiple places.

Comment: OMG, a screenful of code for the simple insert. Your PDO makes code bloated. what's the point in assigning $f_name variable?

Comment: Thanks DCoder! 
No, there are four columns, two are as listed, the other two will be automatically created with DATETIME. 
This is a small example but cover a lots things to me. Five parts in the example for practice to add/delete/view data from database. 1) menu.html, 
2) include.php (for mysql connection), 
3) add-entry.php, 
4) select-entry.php, 
5) delete-entry.php. 
Just started PHP programming, need some time to digest your reply. Thanks a lot!  Greedy favour please, if possible: Can I send you all the files for you to look at for me? Thanks again?

Answer (score -1):

> Unknown column 'address' in 'field list'

Find the query that is using column 'address' in 'field list'.
The one you posted here is apparently not the one issuing this error.
Change your `die(mysqli_error($mysqli));` to

```
trigger_error(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

**for all the queries on the page**
and see certain place where the error occurred.

Also note that you should escape every variable you put in the query as a quoted string, using `mysqli_real_escape_string` (and protect all other variables from the SQL injection) or insert them as a prepared statements.

If your book don't tell you that - burn it!

Comment: thank you halfer for your efforts but it is useless on the sites like this. nobody interested in sane answers, especially the opening poster, who consider himself an expert :)

Comment: $add_address_sql = "INSERT INTO address (master_id, date_added, date_modified, address, city, state, zipcode, type)  
 VALUES ('".$master_id."', now(), now(), '".$_POST["address"]."', 
 '".$_POST["city"]."', '".$_POST["state"]."', '".$_POST["zipcode"]."', '".$_POST["add_type"]."')";
$add_address_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_address_sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
[error] PHP Notice:  Unknown column 'address' in 'field list' in /var/www/addentry.php on line 73, referer: http://localhost/addentry.php
I can't burn the book from the library. Just start PHP. Lots to learn!

Comment: Thanks! Now the example is working, and output what I am expecting. Everything seems fine except the error message (still there but this time in apache error.log instead of my browser): Unknown column 'address' in 'field list' in /var/www/addentry.php on line 73, referer: http://localhost/addentry.php. Have to work on it more. 3:00am in the morning, need go to bed. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Ivan why not just to add this field to the table?

Comment: The problem is I do not know where the field should go.

Comment: THE address TABLE which you're inserting your data into!

Comment: I meant there are 9 fields in the address Table, between which columns I should insert this new field.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10656/discussion-between-ivan-and-your-common-sense)

Comment: @Ivan it doesnt matter. add it wherever you wish